# Filtering Javascript object array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a new array object based on two of them.

```
log1 = {1:"London",2:"New york",4:"Berlin"};
log2 = [{id:1, location:"EU"},{id:2, location:"US"},{id:18, location:"Asia"}];
```

I want to make sure that log1 keys all exist in log2 and, if not, I want to delete it. So for this will be:

```
 result = {1:"London",2:"New york"};
```

I couldn't do it with filter as it take only one object. Is there any way to filter based on two object arrays? Is there any neat way to do it ?

Comment: delete from log1 or log2?

Comment: delete from log1. So log2 is fixed and log1 should change every time log2 dropping an id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a recent version of JS with `Array.map()`, `Array.filter()` and `Object.keys()` you could try the following for a slightly more functional approach:

```
var log1 = {
    1: "London",
    2: "New york",
    4: "Berlin"
};

var log2 = [
    {id: 1,  location: "EU"},
    {id: 2,  location: "US"},
    {id: 18, location: "Asia"}
];


var ids = log2.map(function(obj) { return obj.id; }).map(String);

Object.keys(log1).filter(function(key) {
    return ids.indexOf(key) === -1;
}).forEach(function(k) {
    delete log1[k];
});

console.log(log1);
```

Should yield:

```
{ '1': 'London', '2': 'New york' }
```

Example: http://repl.it/RnF/2

Hope this helps :)

**Edit**

Otherwise, for browser compatibility and much more you could consider lodash or underscore as suggested by other posters. Or use a polyfill!

MDN provides polyfills at the bottom of each of the following pages for older environments (in case you require the compatibility):

- [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: Note: the line `return '' + obj.id;` is just a shortcut to cast the `id` values from `log2` from `number` to `string` because `Object.keys()` will return numeric keys from `log1` as strings.

Comment: I'd probably do `log2.map(function(obj){ return obj.id }).map(String)`

Comment: Ah, of course. That's definitely more succinct - I like that. I'll update my answer to reflect that. Cheers!

Comment: even if this looks so nice i prefer the old way as the performance is much higher...http://jsperf.com/old-vs-new-obj-arr-while anyway nice piece of code

Comment: @cocco that's a really broken benchmark, moreover, it is irrelevant for under thousands of times and thousands of items.

Comment: forEach & filter & map together are slower than a simple for and while loop... btw the oldschool function breaks the loop if the key is found.. if you want you can write a better benchmark.. but you will notice that not much changes...this mix of nice new functions are simply slower.And thinking in large scale the use of various anonymous functions can lead to memory leaks.3 function executions vs 0

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can do it in pure js:

```
    log1 = {1:"London",2:"New york",4:"Berlin"};
    log2 = [{id:1, location:"EU"},{id:2, location:"US"},{id:18, location:"Asia"}];

    for (var prop1 in log1) {
        var found = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < log2.length; i++) {
            if (log2[i].id.toString() === prop1) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            delete log1[prop1]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use http://underscorejs.org/

It has pluck,filter and  map functions that can help you out.. Its quite powerful..

Comment: Native JavaScript has .map and .filter too, and .pluck is just a .map .

Comment: Checkout http://lodash.com/ it's much faster than underscorejs and has the same functionality (+ much more!).